# Capturing the web response stream

Tags: c#, url, stream

When I pass

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi8vJ_lMxQI

as a parameter, the HTML code is downloaded instead of the video.

```
public void StreamDownload(Uri currentUrl)
        {
            int dataLength;
            int bytesRead;

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);
            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            string oFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(URLBox.Text);

            oFileName = AdditionalFunctions.CorrectFname(oFileName); //this function replaces forbidden characters with '♥'.

            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileStream oFile = new FileStream(oFileName,FileMode.Append);

            dataLength = (int)response.ContentLength;

            do
            {
                bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                oFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            while (bytesRead != 0);
        }
```

**Edited due to the comments**
Is there an universal algorithm to extract an video stream from a specified URL? Youtube was only an example.

Comment: The url you're using *is* url to html page. Of course it will be downloaded.

Comment: Your mistake is just thinking that the resource is a video file. If you browse to it, you end up on a web page, not just a video.

Comment: I don't think that question "how to get url for YouTube video" has anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comment: WEBPAGE (what you get from your URL) is something that carries PLAYER component for the media that will be accessed from it by means of some kind of streaming.

So first, you have to parse the web page to find if your stream URL is there somewhere.  If it isn't it would require some kind of network packet capture to determine what connection was recently open from the process that tries to load/play the video, and then capture the data from that connection.

Tricky stuff.

For youtube:

[Downloading video from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably good, but the url you are using is for the web page and not the video-file itself.

Check the html source that is rendered *(Right-click page and "View source")*. You should find the url someway there.

You could also traverse the html from your youtube-link to find the source url in your code.

Comment: After typing "http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflCKdyvw.swf" there is an empty video frame.

Comment: This seems to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @kowalt maybe this is the link then: `<link itemprop="embedURL" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/Zi8vJ_lMxQI?version=3&amp;autohide=1">` ?

Comment: @L.B Of course this is an answer. I'm not just commenting his question but I try to give an answer (tell him what to do). How in the world could that not be an answer? Even if it's wrong, it's still an answer.

Comment: @Mario Now it downloads 3.4 KB of mysterious data

Comment: @kowalt Okay, well, you could try searching the web on how to find the video-file on youtube. I bet there are more tutorials on how to download a video from youtube. Sorry if I couldn't help you enough. Next time =)

Comment: It would be great if the person who voted down could explain why the down vote, so I don't keep repeating the mistake =)

Comment: @Mario I think I explained my reason before about downvote and I still think it is just a comment unless you show how it can be done `You could also traverse the html from your youtube-link to find the source url in your code` =)

Comment: @Mario and what I am curious about is the reason who upvoted your answer. In what way you helped the OP? Can OP continue his work after your answer?

Comment: @L.B I surely upvoted the question because OP should FIRST acknowledge the fact that WEBPAGE is something that carries PLAYER component for the media that will be accessed from it by means of some kind of streaming.

Comment: @L.B Sorry, can not see who downvoted unless that person writes it in the comment.

Comment: @L.B put your mouse OVER upvote arrow.  READ what it says. :)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor Ne need to be cruel. I already read the question and the answer. just see how many people will upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to.  I'm just pointing out that the answer really IS useful.

Comment: @L.B I guess it's really no idea arguing with you. If you do not find it useful, to bad for you. Let's just hope that some people do find it useful.